# Page size specification does not work when saving HTML file as PDF in Chrome using python

Tags: python, html, pdf, selenium-chromedriver

I wanted to open an HTML file on Chrome and save it as a PDF,
I wrote the following code using python, but even I set the "pageSize" in appState in the code to A3, A5, letter size or other size,
the page size of the output PDF file will always be A4.

If I change the values of the other properties "isLandscapeEnabled" or "isHeaderFooterEnabled" in appState, it works well.
So, it seems the "pageSize" property only not works.

And, I found when Control Panel-> Region-> Format (F) is set to Japan, the page size of the output PDF file will always be A4,
and if I set it to the United States, it will always be letter size.
So, I think the "pageSize" is always be set by the default value.

I'm a python beginner and I don't really understand it yet.
Is there something wrong with my code?

Please give me any advice.

- Python 3.9.6
- selenium 3.141.0
- Chrome 94.0.4606.71
- ChromeDriver 94.0.4606.61
- windows10

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import json
import time

def PrintSetUp():
    chopt=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    appState = {
        "recentDestinations": [
            {
                "id": "Save as PDF",
                "origin": "local",
                "account":""
            }
        ],
        "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
        "version": 2,
        "isLandscapeEnabled": False,
        "pageSize": 'A3', 
        "marginsType": 0,
        "scalingType": 3 , 
        "scaling": "100" ,
        "isHeaderFooterEnabled": False, #ヘッダーとフッター
        "isCssBackgroundEnabled": True, #背景のグラフィック
    }
    
    prefs = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState':
             json.dumps(appState),
             "download.default_directory": "~/Downloads"
             }
    chopt.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
    chopt.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
    return chopt

def main_WebToPDF(BlogURL):
    chopt = PrintSetUp()
    driver_path = "C:/Work/pythonTest/Ver94/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe" #webdriverのパス
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=chopt)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10) # 秒 暗示的待機 
    driver.get(BlogURL) #ブログのURL 読み込み
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located)  # ページ上のすべての要素が読み込まれるまで待機（15秒でタイムアウト判定）
    driver.execute_script('return window.print()') #Print as PDF
    time.sleep(10) #ファイルのダウンロードのために10秒待機
    driver.quit() #Close Screen
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    BlogURLList=["file://C:/Work/pythonTest/1_pdf.html",
                 "file://C:/Work/pythonTest/2_pdf.html",
                 "file://C:/Work/pythonTest/3_pdf.html"]
    for BlogURL in  BlogURLList:
        main_WebToPDF(BlogURL)
```

Comment: @K J
I set the default printer to "Adobe PDF" and set the default page size to A3, 
but it didn't affect the page size and remained A4 size when I set the printer to "Save as PDF".
I also set the "mediaSize" with height_microns and width_microns, it doesn't work.
But, I found if I add "name" to"ISO_A4" and "custom_display_name" to "A3" in "mediaSize",it works!
But I don't know why it works.

Comment: The "name" is set to "ISO_A3".